# Having problem in reading data from multi level columns Pivoted format to dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have data in a google sheet with `>200 columns`. In below format: I want to adjust row 1 and 2 in columns to create a dataframe.

```
  0           1          2       3       4
0                     profit    sales   sales
1                     2019      2019    2020
2 Name    Currency    Jan        Feb     Mar
3 Ohashi    JPY        1         22      43
4 Ohashi    JPY        2         23      44
5 Lee       USD        3         24      45
6 Lee       USD        4         25      46
```

original dataset:

[image: there are more than 200 column]
I tried:

```
headers = data[2]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data[2:], columns=headers)
```

result will ignore first two rows. Looking something to bring first two rows in columns also.

**Output Req.**
below groupby with year:

```
Year    Month Name     Transation   Currency    Value
2019    Jan   Ohashi    profit          JPY         1
2019    Jan   Ohashi    profit          JPY         2
2019    Jan   Lee       profit          USD         3
2019    Jan   Lee       profit          USD         4
2019    Feb   Ohashi    sales           JPY         22
2019    Feb   Ohashi    sales           JPY         23
2019    Feb   Lee       sales           USD         24
2019    Feb   Lee       sales           USD         25
2020    Mar   Ohashi    sales           JPY         43
2020    Mar   Ohashi    sales           JPY         44
2020    Mar   Lee       sales           USD         45
2020    Mar   Lee       sales           USD         46
```

Comment: Is possible create `MultiIndex` in columns and index by `pd.read_csv` ?

Comment: @jezrael there are many columns and many years. I will attach the screenshot in the question. Please help :)

Comment: So first step `df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=[0,1], header=[0,1,2,3])` or `df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=[0,1], header=[0,1,2])` not working?

Answer (score 1):

First create `MultiIndex` in `df.index` and `df.columns` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=[0,1], header=[0,1,2,3])
#for remove top level of MultiIndex
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)

print (df)
           profit sales     
             2019  2019 2020
              Jan   Feb  Mar
Ohashi JPY      1    22   43
       JPY      2    23   44
Lee    USD      3    24   45
       USD      4    25   46
       
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('profit', '2019', 'Jan'),
            ( 'sales', '2019', 'Feb'),
            ( 'sales', '2020', 'Mar')],
           )

print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('Ohashi', 'JPY'),
            ('Ohashi', 'JPY'),
            (   'Lee', 'USD'),
            (   'Lee', 'USD')],
           )
```

EDIT:

```
df = df.astype(int).groupby(levels=[0,1,2], axis=1).sum()
```

And then is possible use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with reorder levels by [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html), set index names:

```
df = (df.stack([0,1,2])
        .reorder_levels([3,4,0,2,1])
        .rename_axis(['Year','Month','Name','Transation','Currency'])
        .reset_index(name='Value'))
print (df)
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
        0         1       2      3      4
0                    profit  sales  sales
1                      2019   2019   2020
2    Name  Currency     Jan    Feb    Mar
3  Ohashi       JPY       1     22     43
4  Ohashi       JPY       2     23     44
5     Lee       USD       3     24     45
6     Lee       USD       4     25     46
```

Get 3rd row for index names:

```
names = df.iloc[2]
print (names)
0        Name
1    Currency
2         Jan
3         Feb
4         Mar
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Convert first 2 columns to index:

```
df = df.set_index([0,1])
```

Convert  first 3 rows to MultiIndex columns:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.iloc[:3].T, names=['Transation','Year','Month'])
```

Remove first 3 rows and set index names by variable names:

```
df = df.iloc[3:].rename_axis(names.iloc[:df.index.nlevels].tolist(), axis=0)
print (df)
Transation      profit sales     
Year              2019  2019 2020
Month              Jan   Feb  Mar
Name   Currency                  
Ohashi JPY           1    22   43
       JPY           2    23   44
Lee    USD           3    24   45
       USD           4    25   46
       
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('profit', '2019', 'Jan'),
            ( 'sales', '2019', 'Feb'),
            ( 'sales', '2020', 'Mar')],
           names=['Transation', 'Year', 'Month'])

print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('Ohashi', 'JPY'),
            ('Ohashi', 'JPY'),
            (   'Lee', 'USD'),
            (   'Lee', 'USD')],
           names=['Name', 'Currency'])
```

Reshape, in real data many columns, so removed reorder levels:

```
df = df.stack([0,1,2]).reset_index(name='Value')
print (df)
      Name Currency Transation  Year Month Value
0   Ohashi      JPY     profit  2019   Jan     1
1   Ohashi      JPY      sales  2019   Feb    22
2   Ohashi      JPY      sales  2020   Mar    43
3   Ohashi      JPY     profit  2019   Jan     2
4   Ohashi      JPY      sales  2019   Feb    23
5   Ohashi      JPY      sales  2020   Mar    44
6      Lee      USD     profit  2019   Jan     3
7      Lee      USD      sales  2019   Feb    24
8      Lee      USD      sales  2020   Mar    45
9      Lee      USD     profit  2019   Jan     4
10     Lee      USD      sales  2019   Feb    25
11     Lee      USD      sales  2020   Mar    46
```

Comment: can you** please** look into it ?

Comment: @vishvaschauhan - answer was edited.

Comment: Thanks for update. It can work, I am just one error as there are repeated columns name in row 2 for each year such as jan 2019 , jan 2020 and so on... It is showing error "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis".

Comment: @vishvaschauhan - are data confidental?

Comment: I can show you sample sheet with modified values ..

Comment: @vishvaschauhan - I think not necessary, only one question - are all data numeric in all columns before `stack` ?

Comment: no, data i am reading from formulated google sheet, I was reading each cell as object. I can convert it to number first. It is not numeric

Comment: @vishvaschauhan - Can you try `df = df.astype(int).groupby(levels=[0,1,2], axis=1).sum()` before `stack` ?

Comment: it shows error value base 10 error as all data is not integer, second this "multiple levels only valid with MultiIndex"

Comment: I have requested the client to send raw data without additional sum. It will be fine. :P But i really admire your time and support